# What is the definition of the conformal class of a bilinear form?

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

In the fourth line you can see. It talks about conformal class of a Levi form.

I know what a conformal map is, but I can't deduce what a conformal class is from this.

[image: ppp]

Can somebody help me? Many thanks!

Comment: Apparently the author means that multiplying by $r$ does not change $L_M$, but it's hard to understand if I don't know what is $g$ and $r$.

Comment: He never speaks about $g$. He previously speaked avout $r$: it's a real twice differentiable function (defined on $\Bbb C^n$). I think $g$ is the same.

Comment: From where is this piece of text? From what I've seen the author just mean the last identity as the independence of conformal class. By conformal class, in this sense, just means the set $\{gL_M | g\neq 0 \}$. I presume $r$ is the equation defining the hyper surface, then multiplying by a non-zero function $g$ is a conformal map  (in each tangent vector space).

Comment: It's a book written by my teacher (whose is not available at now, otherwise I'd asked him). If you want I can pass it to you, just give me your email